# How to remove optional text from json Result In swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I am using newsApi to get list of news from it. I created model based on news's property, all property are optional in model and as i parse it printed to console getting result but all fields have data with optional text

I have created three struct based on news api fields, They are like

```
struct GoogleNews: Codable {
   var status: String?
   var totalResults: Int?
   var articles: [Article]
  }

struct Article: Codable {
   var source: Source
   var author: String?
   var title: String?
   var description: String?
   var url: String?
   var urlToImage: String?
   var publishedAt: String?
  var content: String?
}

struct Source: Codable {
   var id: String?
   var name: String?
}
```

Calling the appi

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {return}

        do {
            let allNews = try JSONDecoder().decode(GoogleNews.self, from: data)
            print(allNews.articles[0])
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }.resume()
```

After calling the api, in result all fields are having result with optional text

```
name: Optional("Venturebeat.com")), author: Optional("Dean Takahashi"), title: Optional("How Paymentwall’s Terminal3 lets game developers create their own online shops"), description: Optional("Paymentwall built a business as a global payments platform, with much of its focus on games. Last year, the company spun out its Terminal3 as a platform for monetizing and distributing games. Now it is making it easier for indie, small, and medium-size game c…")...ect
```

What should be the solution to remove the optional text from the results..

Comment: The values are optional because **you** declared the struct members as optional.

Comment: @vadian thanks for response, i have to make it optional in struct because some fields have nil values also,

Comment: @sham, can't you just override `description` and return whatever string you want it to return?

Comment: ***Some** fields* but certainly not all. Use Optional Bindings to unwrap the optionals safely.

Comment: You can use either `flatMap` or `compactMap` on the `allNew.articles` array to filter out nil values and get rid of `Optional`. Try `allName.articles.flatMap({ $0.author  })` for example. It really depends on what you want to do with the data. Generally the best way would be to use `!` over `?` because it will create a nil value by default rather than having the `Optional`

Comment: Using optional Binding
if let constantName = someOptional {
   //statements using 'constantName' 
} else {
// the value of someOptional is not set (or nil).
}

Answer (score 2):

For the values in your struct that are optional, be sure they're optionals because you know for sure that there are cases where a value won't be returned. If you'd like to unwrap them, you have 2 ways of doing so.

The first way is to use an *if-let statement*, which would look something like this:

```
if let name = allNews.articles[0].name {

}
```

Within the curly braces is where you would use the variable *name*, which wouldn't be the optional value you're asking about because it's been unwrapped.

The second method you could use is a *guard statement*, which looks like this:

```
guard let name = allNews.articles[0].name else { return }
```

In this instance, the *name* variable would be unwrapped and can be used anywhere in the scope of your code. However, it's only valid if it can be successfully unwrapped. If it cannot, then the return statement is called and breaks out of whatever scope it's in.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you're trying to print an object which all properties are optionals. You have to unwrap the properties even if you unwrap the `article` . You can unwrap your optionals like this:

```
let article = allNews.articles[0] 
if let source = article.source {
    print(source)
}
```

Also you can unwrap more than one property at once:

```
if let source = article.source, let author = article.author, let title = article.title {
   // do things
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the sign of ? from the end of the Struct members declaration to become like this:

```
let author: String
```